# How to Toggle state from within map-gl-js on clicking the map using hooks

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to toggle the state of `focus_img_id` on everytime a user clicks on the map.
This is a code snippet of logic which will be used to highlight point clicked on by user and then revert it back to original color on second click.

1 -> Why does the set `focus_img_id === 0` always evaluate `true`?

2 -> Why does the toggle work here and not in 1.

2 -> Why does it fire multiple times?

CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/green-tree-5qtj4?file=/src/App.js:1216-1234

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl"; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax

mapboxgl.accessToken =
'pk.eyJ1IjoiendlbHN0ZXJuIiwiYSI6ImNreHE1cmZlajUxYWozMHBmdnoyOTl0dDQifQ.4AQBzB3LzGjE72d_9iSWSA';

export default function App() {
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  const [lng, setLng] = useState(138.603451251989);
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(-34.929553631263);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(18);

  const [focus_img_id, setFocus_img_id] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    // INITIALIZE MAP
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainerRef.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom
    });

    map.on("load", () => {
      // ***************************
      // 1. UPDATES STATE BUT 
      // Always enter the condition if (focus === null)
      // even though the state is set to 2 after clicking
      // ****************************      
      // map.on("click", (e) => {
      //   if (focus_img_id === 2) {
      //     setFocus_img_id(0);
      //   }
      //   if (focus_img_id === 0) {
      //     setFocus_img_id(2);
      //   }
      // });
      // ****************************
      setMap(map);
    });
    return () => map.remove();
  },[]);


  // 2. WORKS FINE HERE | 
  // BUT FOR SOME REASON THIS FUNCTION FIRES
  // MULTIPLE TIMES
  // ****************************
  if(map)
  {
    map.on("click", (e) => {
      if (focus_img_id === 2) {
        setFocus_img_id(0);
      }
      if (focus_img_id === 0) {
        setFocus_img_id(2);
      }
      console.log("{onclick} focus:",focus_img_id)
    });
  }
  // ****************************

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("{UseEffect} focus :",focus_img_id)
  },[focus_img_id])
  // ****************************

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="sidebarStyle">
        Focus : {focus_img_id}
      </div>
      <div ref={mapContainerRef} className="map-container" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. your focus focus_img_id is always 0, because you subscribe to your click event on your load. you can set a ref value, if you want to get the correct changed value of focus_img_id.

   ```
   const focus_img_idRef = useRef(0);
   if (focus_img_idRef.current === 2) {
      focus_img_idRef.current = 0;
   }
   if (focus_img_idRef.current === 0) {
      focus_img_idRef.current = 2;
   }
   ```
2. it fires multiple times because you subscribe to a event multiple times. try like this:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       if(map) {
         map.on("click", (e) => {
             if (focus_img_id === 2) {
             setFocus_img_id(0);
             }
             if (focus_img_id === 0) {
                 setFocus_img_id(2);
             }
             console.log("{onclick} focus:",focus_img_id)
         });
       }
       return () => {
           //unsubcribe here.
           map.off("click", (e) => {
               ...your code...
           })
       }
   }, [map])
   ```